# Only receive string 'admin' on controller store function Laravel 6

Tags: php, vuejs2, axios, laravel-6

I want to be able to register a Laravel user from my Vue front end so i can create employee accounts. 
I build a data object in the front and send the ovject with a post request to my `/api/v1/users` route what routes to `UserController@store`.

Axios post:

```
  ...

  getHeaders() {
    return {headers: {
      "Content-Type": 'application/json',
      "accept": "application/json",
    }}
  },

  ...

  postRequest(extraHeaders = {}) {
    let body = {"key": "Whoow"};
    console.log("Body:", body);

    axios.post(
      method: 'post',
      url: "http://${subDomain}.domain.lan/api/v1/users",
      headers: this.getHeaders(),
      body: body,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("response", response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      return error;
    });
  },

   ...
```

The request payload in devtools shows me: `{key: "Whoow"}` what is exactly the same as printed in the console: `Body: {key: "Whoow"}`
In my `UserController@store` i receive only the string "admin" as `$data`

```
    ...

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
    ...

    protected function store(Request $data)
    {
      Log::debug("Request received");
      Log::debug(gettype($data));
      Log::debug($data->all());

      return response()->json(["name" => "Pieter"]);
    }

    ...
```

The laravel log shows me this:

```
[2019-10-16 22:00:27] local.DEBUG: Request received  
[2019-10-16 22:00:27] local.DEBUG: string  
[2019-10-16 22:00:27] local.DEBUG: admin
```

In the front end i receive the response correctly:

```
response {name: "Pieter"}
```

in case it matters, my route:

```
Route::post('/api/v1/registrations', 'Auth\RegisterController@store');
```

According to the laravel docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests) i shoud receive a `Request` object. I have no idea why i receive something different than actually post.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance in your `store` method of controller. So try some thing as follow;

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    dd($request->all()); // you should get all the params
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentoining but i already tried this as well. I just tried it again: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;` at the top of the file, `Request $data` as param, and `Log::debug($data->all());`. The result: `[2019-10-16 08:09] local.DEBUG: admin ` i updated my question also. Thx any way!

Answer (score 0):

public function store(Request $request)
{

```
return $request; // you will get all the params using return statement
```

}

Comment: This is similar to what i do (`Request $data`) and for some reason `$data` only contains a `string` with the value `admin` instead of the request data. I don't want to return the `$data` to the front-end, i want to use it to create some (user) objects and store them to the database as explained in my question.